# How do I refer itself's value in dynamic linq to XML?

Tags: linq-to-xml

I'm using Scott Gu's dynamic linq library for Linq to XMl. The problem is I don't know how to refer an element itself value inside of the dynamic query.

What I want to do is as follows:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
var ret = doc.Descendants("Row").Where(x => x.Element("ID").Value == "2").ToList();
```

I want to replace the where clause to dynamic linq, but I don't know how I should rewrite it. I tried as follows:

```
var ret = doc.Descendants("Row").Where("Element(""ID"").Value == @0", "2").ToList();
```

But it gives me an error saying "There is no property named Element" or something.

Could anyone please tell me how to do that?

Thanks in advance,
Yoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I did a trick. It's not great but works. It might cause a performance problem, but for now, it's okay.

```
var doc.Descendants("Row").Select(x => x.Element("ID").Value).Where("Value == @0", "2").Select(x => x.Parent).ToList();
```

If you have a better solution, please post it here.

Thanks,
Yoo